# Can I access sdf (SQL Server Compact database file) kept at some other computer on the same network?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I have done so for SQL Server, now I was trying to do it SQL Server Compact.

I am unable to make a connection string in SQL Server Compact which has the provision for providing ip/server.

Comment: SQL Server CE is **not** intended for network use - it's a **local-machine only** "database" (or cache) - not a network-ready database system.

Comment: it does not seem logical that i can't access the sdf, such a handicap if that is the case.

Comment: SQL Server Compact is just **not designed** to be used in a network. It's designed as a **local-only** cache/database store. It was a **design decision** made by its authors ... if you need something that works for multiple users in a network - use the **real** SQL Server (Express or any other edition).

Comment: how are we supposed to extract info from the sdf then? I mean i've used the software to deploy at some place. Obviously i would not want to go there everytime i want some info.

Comment: You can use something like the Sync Framework to get the data back to an SQL Server.

Comment: Put a **service** on top of that data! I would never recommend to remotely access some data directly anyway ....

Comment: i just want to use it for the local network with proper authentication.

Comment: Ain't sync framework like using a dropbox?

Comment: since SQL Server Compact is not designed for newtwork use ( because it's a file, like Microsoft Access and Sqlite), then you have 2 choices, change the DB to something else (SqlServer), or, download the file, modify it and upload it dans frankly I dont like the second choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Replicating Data to a remote server.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152568(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Added new community wiki answer covering links provided by Amber and also merged comments into answer. Feel free to vote to delete from review.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact is just not designed to be used in a network. It's designed as a local-only cache/database store. It was a design decision made by its authors ... if you need something that works for multiple users in a network - use the real SQL Server (Express or any other edition) (by [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758857/can-i-access-sdf-sql-server-compact-database-file-kept-at-some-other-computer#comment18911104_13758857)

It is also considered bad idea to expose SQL server to network - you may want to redesign your application to have service exposing limited functionality to users and calling DB (in this case you *can* use local SQL compact, but still consider other editions that are more appropriate to general data storage).

If SQL Compact is requirement - replicate data to local file - [MSDN:Replicating Data to SQL Server Compact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152568(v=sql.105).aspx).

For more information on Sql Compact connection strings - [Connecting C# to SQL Server Compact database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157368/connecting-c-sharp-to-sql-server-compact-database)